# Lucene.NET update not removing search terms

Tags: indexing, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.NET for a project, and creating an index/searching the index is going great. However, when I update, I seem to only **add** to the search index, but never **remove** terms from the index. Rebuilding the index from scratch fixes things, but obviously I'd prefer not to do that every time somebody modifies a value.

- As an example, say we have indexed DocumentA with a field FieldB with the text "This is some text to index."
- Searching for the word "fantastic" yields no results.
- Now, we update FieldB of DocumentA to "This is some fantastic text to index."
- Searching for the word "fantastic" yields DocumentA as a result (as expected).
- Update FieldB of DocumentA to "This is some mediocre text to index."
- Searching for "mediocre" yields DocumentA as a result (as expected).
- Searching for "fantastic" **still yields DocumentA as a result**. This is not the behavior I expect or want.

Here is the method I'm using to update the document (class names changed to protect the innocent):

```
internal static void ModifyDocuments(IEnumerable<SomeFancyObject> changed)
{
    if (changed.Count() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    var dir = FSDirectory.Open(LuceneGlobals.directory);
    var writer = new IndexWriter(dir, LuceneGlobals.analyzer, false, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(int.MaxValue));

    foreach (var fancyObj in changed) {
        //writer.DeleteDocuments(new Term("fancyID", fancyObj.ID.ToString()));
        //writer.AddDocument(CreateDocument(fancyObj));
        writer.UpdateDocument(new Term("fancyID", fancyObj.ID.ToString()), CreateDocument(index));
    }

    writer.Optimize();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Note that I have tried the code as written, and also the commented out Delete/Add in place of the Update call. I also tried `writer.Commit();` in place of `writer.Optimize();`.

Debugging reveals that the entire method is executed, and `CreateDocument()` creates a new document with the data I am expecting to see. Here's the `CreateDocument()` for completeness:

```
private static Document CreateDocument(SomeFancyObject fancyObj)
{
    var doc = new Document();

    doc.Add(new Field("docType", "SomeFancyObject", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

    doc.Add(new Field("fancyID", Convert.ToString(fancyObj.ID), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
    doc.Add(new Field("fancyText", new StringReader(fancyObj.Text)));
    doc.Add(new Field("fancyTitle", new StringReader(fancyObj.Title)));

    return doc;
}
```

I'm seeing what I expect to see in `fancyObj.Text` and `fancyObj.Title`. Perhaps I'm not using all the options correctly here?

What needs to be done to keep my index from remembering data that has been updated away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to index (`Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`) fancyID. `IndexWriter.UpdateDocument` removes all with a matching term, but no terms are generated unless you index it.

You could also look into reading the value from FieldCache, instead of storing it.